# Type Orm add array with object to entity

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nestjs, typeorm

As a relult I need icons as array with objects inside, just like here:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Title text",
        "icons": [
            {
                "icon": "icon-1.png",
                "main": true
            },
            {
                "icon": "icon-2.png",
                "main": false
            },
            {
                "icon": "icon-3.png",
                "main": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Entities are:

```
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  title: string;
```

But how create icons?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new entity and join it, or you can use `jsonb` type

```
  ...
  @Column({ type: 'jsonb', nullable: true, default: [] })
  icons: Icons[];
  ...
```

and your Icons like this:

```
export interface Icons {
  icon: string;
  main: boolean;
}
```